# Does non-negative $\mathbf{A}$ imply non-negative $\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

If $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{nxm}$ is non-negative, is $\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}$ also non-negative?
Is there an associated lemma/theorem?

Comment: This is trivial by just looking at the equations for the individual elements of $\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}$; each one is a sum of products of non-negative terms, and therefore non-negative.

Comment: Assuming you mean that all elements of $A$ are non-negative, then yes.

Comment: Do you mean elementwise or as in definiteness?

Comment: I mean elementwise non-negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sense of positivity for matrices and operators, this is true even if $A$ is not non-negative since for any vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$
$$
x\cdot (A^TA) · x = (Ax)\cdot(Ax) = |Ax|^2 ≥ 0
$$